# Weird text returns a readable text on pdf. How can I decode that?

Tags: java, php, pdf, character-encoding, encode

If I open the pdf and search for these bold letters, the browser will find them. What type of text is that? How can I decode that?

[image: Image Example]

Comment: What language are you using? Where's your code?

Comment: Please share the pdf in question.